# Simplify writing custom iterators in Java

Tags: c#, java, collections, iterator, yield-return

Writing iterators for custom collections in Java is quite complicated, because instead of writing straight-forward code that provides one element after the other, you essentially have to write a state machine:

```
public class CustomCollection<T> implements Iterable<T>
{
    private T[] data;
    private int size;

    @Override
    public Iterator<T> iterator()
    {
        return new Iterator<T>()
        {
            private int cursor = 0;

            @Override
            public boolean hasNext()
            {
                return cursor < size;
            }

            @Override
            public T next()
            {
                return data[cursor++];
            }

            @Override
            public void remove()
            {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
            }
        };
    }
    // ...
}
```

For collections more complicated than an array list or a linked list, getting these state machines correctly is a daunting task. In fact, the C# design team deemed writing custom iterators complicated enough to introduce special language support (`yield return`) for letting the compiler build the state machines.

Is something like `yield return` coming in the next version of Java? Or are there any library solutions that make my life easier when it comes to writing my own iterators in Java?

Comment: I've done cover of all java collections/maps for a JDO impl. it's not so hard at all, also the you dont want IndexOutOfBounds on `next()` but `NoSuchElementException()`, and effectively the iterator can go w/o using `hasNext()` only `next()` passing the mark of `size()`

Comment: @bestsss Sure iterating a collection is quite trivial in almost every case (the current position can be easily recorded, either as a Node or an index, or index and position,..) but generally yield would still be extremely useful for many complex scenarios. But alas it doesn't seem to be coming - pity though.

Comment: @Voo, often than not it was iterating a JDBC result not the real collection w/ caching the results meanwhile (that's for lazy loaded collections/maps)

Comment: No, something like `yield return` will not be in Java 7 (which will be out this summer) and is also not planned for Java 8 (planned for the end of 2012). I don't know about C#, but in Java writing your own iterators is not something that you'd usually do, so I doubt that this would be something that you'd want special language support for.

Comment: @Voo, on a side note why is that discontent to the state machines, they can be extremely useful in a lot of cases and esp. in concurrent programming.

Comment: I guess this is something you don't usually do in Java, because you don't have language-level support for it.

Comment: @bestsss I don't see where I state discontent for state machines? State machines are perfectly fine, they're some extremely important and useful cornerstones of CS after all. And when doing some work in Verilog/VHDL state machines are the tool of choice more often enough. What I'm discontent with is having to implement a state machine myself in a high level programming language although other languages had support for a yield statement for years. Why write lots of boilerplate code when the compiler should be able to do it themselves?

Comment: @Voo, I didn't mean you, personally, but almost any developer has nightmares with them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java has always provided a mechanism for maintaining state and continuing execution at a later point in time: threads. The basic idea for my library solution is to let a `ConcurrentIterable` *produce* the elements in one thread, and let a `ConcurrentIterator` *consume* them in another, communicating via a bounded queue. (This is generally known as the producer/consumer pattern.)

First, here is a demonstration of the simplified usage:

```
public class CustomCollection<T> extends ConcurrentIterable<T>
{
    private T[] data;
    private int size;

    @Override
    protected void provideElements()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        {
            provideElement(data[i]);
        }
    }
    // ...
}
```

Note the complete absence of state machines. All you have to do is derive from `ConcurrentIterable` and implement the method `provideElements`. Inside this method, you write straight-forward code which calls `provideElement` for each element in the collection.

Sometimes a client does not iterate through the entire collection, for example in a linear search. You can stop providing elements as soon as an abortion is detected by checking `iterationAborted()`:

```
    @Override
    protected void provideElements()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < size && !iterationAborted(); ++i)
        {
            provideElement(data[i]);
        }
    }
```

It is perfectly fine not to check `iterationAborted()`, as long as you do not care about the additional elements being generated. With infinite sequences, checking `iterationAborted()` is mandatory.

How can the producer detect that the consumer has stopped iterating? This is implemented by having a strong reference to a token in the consumer and a weak reference to that same token in the producer. When the consumer stops iterating, the token becomes eligible for garbage collection, and it will eventually become invisible to the producer. From then on, all new elements will simply be discarded.

(Without this precaution, under certain circumstances the bounded queue could eventually fill up, the producer would enter an infinite loop, and the contained elements would never be garbage collected.)

And now for the implementation details:

### ConcurrentIterable.java

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public abstract class ConcurrentIterable<T> implements Iterable<T>
{
    private static final int CAP = 1000;
    private final ThreadLocal<CommunicationChannel<T>> channels
    = new ThreadLocal<CommunicationChannel<T>>();

    @Override
    public Iterator<T> iterator()
    {
        BlockingQueue<Option<T>> queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<Option<T>>(CAP);
        Object token = new Object();
        final CommunicationChannel<T> channel
        = new CommunicationChannel<T>(queue, token);
        new Thread(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                channels.set(channel);
                provideElements();
                enqueueSentinel();
            }
        }).start();
        return new ConcurrentIterator<T>(queue, token);
    }

    protected abstract void provideElements();

    protected final boolean iterationAborted()
    {
        return channels.get().iterationAborted();
    }

    protected final void provideElement(T element)
    {
        enqueue(Option.some(element));
    }

    private void enqueueSentinel()
    {
        enqueue(Option.<T> none());
    }

    private void enqueue(Option<T> element)
    {
        try
        {
            while (!offer(element))
            {
                System.gc();
            }
        }
        catch (InterruptedException ignore)
        {
            ignore.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private boolean offer(Option<T> element) throws InterruptedException
    {
        CommunicationChannel<T> channel = channels.get();
        return channel.iterationAborted()
            || channel.queue.offer(element, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
}
```

### CommunicationChannel.java

```
import java.lang.ref.WeakReference;
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;

public class CommunicationChannel<T>
{
    public final BlockingQueue<Option<T>> queue;
    private final WeakReference<Object> token;

    public CommunicationChannel(BlockingQueue<Option<T>> queue, Object token)
    {
        this.queue = queue;
        this.token = new WeakReference<Object>(token);
    }

    public boolean iterationAborted()
    {
        return token.get() == null;
    }
}
```

### ConcurrentIterator.java

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;

public class ConcurrentIterator<T> implements Iterator<T>
{
    private final BlockingQueue<Option<T>> queue;
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private final Object token;
    private Option<T> next;

    public ConcurrentIterator(BlockingQueue<Option<T>> queue, Object token)
    {
        this.queue = queue;
        this.token = token;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext()
    {
        if (next == null)
        {
            try
            {
                next = queue.take();
            }
            catch (InterruptedException ignore)
            {
                ignore.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return next.present;
    }

    @Override
    public T next()
    {
        if (!hasNext()) throw new NoSuchElementException();
        T result = next.value;
        next = null;
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public void remove()
    {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
}
```

### Option.java

```
public class Option<T>
{
    public final T value;
    public final boolean present;

    private Option(T value, boolean present)
    {
        this.value = value;
        this.present = present;
    }

    public static <T> Option<T> some(T value)
    {
        return new Option<T>(value, true);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static <T> Option<T> none()
    {
        return none;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
    private static final Option none = new Option(null, false);
}
```

Let me know what you think!

Comment: You know this is your own question, and you asked it less than half an hour ago, right?

Comment: I imagine this works, but in general it doesn't seem worth the overhead of creating a thread, etc. just so you can write an iterator as a loop.

Comment: @DeadMG: What's the matter, are you surprised I didn't post my own answer within a couple of seconds, as I usually do? ;)

Comment: I am not sure what you wish to achieve via threads. Threads and context switches are not free. Most, likely you've a race condition in ConcurrentIterator.next() if you attempt to throw an exception on an empty queue, the block must be synchronized in a similar way as isEmpty(). Although isEmpty() doesn't guarantee proper results either. A better approach is using look ahead and polling the queue both in hasNext and next if the element==null.

Comment: @best: The polling idea sounds promising, thank you. What race condition are you talking about, specifically? And are you saying that `isEmpty` may generally return incorrect results? Does the API explicitly say that somewhere?

Comment: @Fred, the check for `if (!hasNext()) throw new NoSuchElementException();` is practically irrelevant in a concurrent environment, if there is more a single consumer of the queue. In such a case: hasNext() sees an element but it's already polled by another thread and the 1st threads block in take() forever.

Comment: @best: I am aware of the general problem, but in this case, there is only ever one consumer per queue. I really want to process every element without someone else stealing some of my work :)

Comment: As we've [discussed in the chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/893189#893189), this solution will keep the producer thread around forever if the client abandons iteration in the middle, like when doing a search on the sequence. That implies no garbage collection for all objects rooted by that thread.

Comment: @DeadMG: So what? Are you new to Stack Overflow or something? No, you're not.

Comment: @Martinho: Iteration abortion should no longer be an issue, see my update.

Answer (score 5):

No, Java doesn't have anything like `yield`. As far as libraries, [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com) has a number of helpful classes to make certain kinds of iterators easy to write:

- `AbstractIterator` just requires you to implement a `T computeNext()` method.
- `AbstractLinkedIterator` requires you to implement `T computeNext(T previous)`.

`AbstractIterator` could be used for this as follows:

```
return new AbstractIterator<T>() {
  private int index = 0;

  protected T computeNext() {
    return index == size ? endOfData() : data[index++];
  }
};
```

You could also use `Arrays.asList` as Amir suggested, or even do something like this:

```
private final List<T> listView = new AbstractList<T>() {
  public int size() {
    return data.length;
  }

  public T get(int index) {
    return data[index];
  }
};

public Iterator<T> iterator() {
  return listView.iterator();
}
```

Comment: make sure you impl. RandomAccess or the list will be a red-head step child to the `Collections` utility methods. But yeah, AbstractList is quite handy for exactly such cases.

Comment: +1 for mentioning Guava, which does go quite a ways towards the general concern here.

Comment: @bestsss: In that example I was just referring to keeping an internal list view as a source of iterators, so it wouldn't be exposed. But really, the `CustomCollection` itself could extend `AbstractList` if desired, in which case you'd definitely want it to implement `RandomAccess`.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe I am just not understanding your questions. Can you not do `return Arrays.asList(data).iterator()`

Answer (score 0):

if you don't mind starting a new thread it's possible using a [SynchronousQueue](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/SynchronousQueue.html)

```
public class InternalIterator<T> implements Iterator<T>{

    private SynchronousQueue<T> queue = new SynchronousQueue<T>();
    private volatile boolean empty = false;
    private T current =null;
    private Object lock = new Object();

    private Runner implements Runnable{//run in deamon

        public void run(){
            //iterate and call 
            synchronized()(lock){
                try{
                    queue.offer(t);
                    lock.wait();
                }catch(InteruptedException e){
                    empty=true;
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            } 
            //for each element to insert this will be the yield return 

            emtpy=true;
        }

    }

    public boolean hasNext(){
        if(current!=null)return true;

        while(!empty){
            if( (current=queue.poll(100,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS))!=null){//avoid deadlock when last element is already returned but empty wasn't written yet 
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    public boolean next(){
        if(!hasNext())throw new NoSuchElementException();
        T tmp = current;
        current=null;
        return tmp;
    }

    public void remove(){
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }


}
```